# Comparing column datas to a specific row's value results in ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def Test(file):
    trialGroup = (file["x_counter"] == 0)
    groupNum = file.loc[trialGroup].tail(1)["completed"]
    indicesToDelete = (file["completed"] == groupNum)
    return file.loc[indicesToDelete]
```

The above code is outputting the error "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" on the fourth line with the indicesToDelete. groupNum gets the data of the last row in trialGroup in column "completed", which is an integer. The fourth line runs into an error when it gets compared to groupNum but works fine if an integer was directly placed in it.
[Test file used in function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/789Ej.png)
[Used the number 2 to replace groupNum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NhwG.png)

I tried returning the groupNum to see what it would output, and it says 2. Not seeing the difference between directly using an integer and the variable groupNum.[returning groupNum variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpvhV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `groupNum` is not an integer, it's a Series of length 1. I've created a mock dataframe to check it:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.DataFrame({
    "something": [1, 2, 3],
    "completed": [2, 2, 3]
})

trialGroup = [True, True, False]
groupNum = file.loc[trialGroup].tail(1)["completed"]
print(type(groupNum))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

You can take the last value an actually get an integer like this for example:

```
type(file.loc[trialGroup].iloc[-1]["completed"])
# numpy.int64
```